# Detect logging framework when writing Java Library

Tags: java, logging

I'm writing a java library which will be used by some external web applications. Let's assume that each application can use different logging system, say App A uses slf4j over log4j and App B: uses log4j2 over logback (Log4j2 -> slf4j -> logback) or just plain logback.

Now I would like to use current logging framework to log some messages from the library.

1. Which way I can detect  logging system which is currently used by the client?
2. How to dynamically log to detected logging system?

I did something like that before by detecting if particular classes (typical to slf4j) are on classpath and than used some "loggingService" which was logging directly to slf4j. I'm wondering if this is correct approach or how else this can be tackled?

Comment: I think your question goes into the "opinionated" area. "what is the best way" is way too unspecific. For one person, whatever works is "best", others might have much harder requirements. imho: your approach sounds OK to me.

Comment: @GhostCat: point taken. I rephrased question one. Thanks for your opinion.

Comment: Log4J2 over Logback? You mean Log4J2 -> SLF4J -> Logback?

Comment: @Kayman: Yes this is what I meant...I'll fix that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The normal way is to pick your logging API and have the application that uses your library provide an implementation for it (which can be just a bridge to whatever backend will actually be used).

For example, your library would build against `slf4j-api`. If the app wants to use Log4J, it would provide a) Log4J and b) a bridge from SLF4J to Log4J (so that you can log via SLF4J and it still ends up in Log4J).

Do not try to detect anything.

> say App A uses slf4j over log4j and App B: uses log4j2 over logback

In the above example, App A is already set up to consume your library (because it provides slf4j-api), and App B is also ready (because it provides logback, which happens to also bring in slf4j-api). If App B used log4j2 over j.u.l, it would need to also pull in a bridge from sfl4j to j.u.l).

In general, there will be only one logging *backend* (decided and configured by the application), but there can be many logging *API* (so that all libraries that you need can have the one they like) that pipe into it.

The only reason code would ever want to detect and talk directly to the logging backend is if you need to programmatically configure it. Usually only application bootstrap code needs to do that (if at all). For the actual logging, you just talk to the API (of your choice).

Comment: This sounds good, as log4j2 also provides a bridge between log4j2 and slf4j, so as you suggested I will build against slf4j-spi.... but what would you say for following situation: Application C is legacy one and uses log4j and application owner does not want to provide a bridge.. also there is Applocation D using logback where bridge is not allowed. I know this may sound awkward (and it is not my case actually) but this would be another reason for detecting the loggin systems IMHO.

Comment: If Application C or Application D want to use this library, they need to provide a logging backend for the API that the library needs. There is no reason to not add this (if a particular implementation is disallowed, there could be custom one, or a noop-logger). It can be seen as a required dependency of the library. If your library needs to work with just the JDK, you could use j.u.l. (but that's a bit painful).

Comment: OK,.This is reasonable. I will go agains slft4j-api as you suggested.